# flutter: error after pub add path_provider

Tags: flutter

im getting an error after only installing path_provider with

> flutter pub add path_provider

error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.0.2/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.0.2/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited
```

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean && flutter pub get` and tried again?

Comment: tried already, still the same error

Comment: you'll have to investigate better or edit your question with more intel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With homebrew, try using any cask command. Try this command for example, work for me:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask
```